# Update Stock value after product invoice in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a project on Pharmacy inventory management. I two models Medicine and Medicine Sale, code is mentioned below. I want to update the stock value inventory of each medicine when I generate a sale.e:g If I sell 3 quantities of a product, that quantity should be removed from the stock value of that product.  Can anyone guide me?

Here is the **models.py** file which has both classes of Medicine and Medicine Sale

```py
class Medicine(models.Model):

    medicine_choices = (
        ('Tablet', 'Tablet'),
        ('Syrup', 'Syrup'),
        ('Granules', 'Granules'),
        ('Capsules', 'Capsules'),
        ('Injection', 'Injection'),
        ('Supplements', 'Suplements'),
    )

    year_choices = (
        ('2021', '2021'),
        ('2022', '2022'),
        ('2023', '2023'),
        ('2024', '2024'),
        ('2025', '2025'),
        ('2026', '2026'),
    )
    medicine_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    medicine_type = models.CharField(choices=medicine_choices, max_length=100)
    stock_value = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    expiry_date = models.CharField(choices=year_choices, max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.medicine_name


class MedicineSale(models.Model):

    medicine1 = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, related_name = 'first_medicine', on_delete=CASCADE)
    qty_no_1 = models.FloatField()
    price_no_1 = models.FloatField()
    total_amt1 =  models.FloatField(editable=False, default=0)

    medicine2 = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, related_name = 'second_medicine', on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True)
    qty_no_2 = models.FloatField()
    price_no_2 = models.FloatField()
    total_amt2 =  models.FloatField(editable=False, default=0)

    medicine3 = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, related_name = 'third_medicine', on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True)
    qty_no_3 = models.FloatField()
    price_no_3 = models.FloatField()
    total_amt3 =  models.FloatField(editable=False, default=0)

    medicine4 = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, related_name = 'fourth_medicine', on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True)
    qty_no_4 = models.FloatField()
    price_no_4 = models.FloatField()
    total_amt4 =  models.FloatField(editable=False, default=0)

    total = models.FloatField(editable=False, default=0)
    sale_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.total_amt1 = self.qty_no_1*self.price_no_2
        self.total_amt2 = self.qty_no_2*self.price_no_2
        self.total_amt3 = self.qty_no_3*self.price_no_3
        self.total_amt4 = self.qty_no_4*self.price_no_4
        self.total = self.total_amt1+self.total_amt2+self.total_amt3+self.total_amt4
        super(MedicineSale, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Here is the admin.py file

```py
class MedicineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('medicine_name', 'medicine_type', 'stock_value', 'price', 'expiry_date')
    list_display_links = ('medicine_name',)
    search_fields = ('medicine_name', 'medicine_type', 'expiry_date')
    list_filter = ('medicine_type', 'expiry_date')

    

class MedicineSaleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'total', 'sale_date' )


admin.site.register(Medicine, MedicineAdmin)
admin.site.register(MedicineSale,MedicineSaleAdmin)
```

Comment: What if you have more that 4 medicines in one sale? You should create another table called `MedicineSaleItem` that is a "child" of `MedicineSale` so you can have as many items in a sale, as needed.

Comment: Yes but for now client requirement is only for maximum 4 or less items in the invoice.